# How to get side by side icon and label in tab navigator

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve row-wise icon and label for a tab navigator in one of my project. I am able to set icon and label as per the default settings, but i want the icon to be on the left side and label on the right not as icon on top and label on bottom.

This is my code:

```
export const InnerTab = TabNavigator({
Map: {
    screen: MapStack,
    navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Map',
          tabBarIcon:  (
                <Image source={require('../logos/map.png')}
                       style={[styles.innerTabIcon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
                />
          )
    },
},
List: {
    screen: ListStack,
    navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'List',
          tabBarIcon:  (
                <Image source={require('../logos/list.png')}
                       style={[styles.innerTabIcon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
                />
          )
    },
},
},
{
tabBarPosition: 'top',
animationEnabled: false,
swipeEnabled:false,
lazy:true,
tabBarOptions: {
upperCaseLabel: false,
showIcon: true,
activeBackgroundColor:'#2394C7',
inactiveBackgroundColor:'#77909F',
tabStyle:{
  marginTop:(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 0 : 0,
  height : 40,

},
 indicatorStyle: {
    backgroundColor : '#2394C7',
    height :(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 53 :  63,
  },

 style :{
     backgroundColor:'#77909F'
 },
labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight:'bold',
     marginTop: 0,
     color :'#ffffff'
},
},
});
```

I have gone through the docs but found none. But tried few ways but didnt work.

Is there any way i can achieve it??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add `flexDirection:'row'` to `tabStyle` under `tabBarOptions`.

Reference:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab

```
tabBarOptions: {
upperCaseLabel: false,
showIcon: true,
activeBackgroundColor:'#2394C7',
inactiveBackgroundColor:'#77909F',
tabStyle:{
  marginTop:(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 0 : 0,
  height : 40,
  flexDirection: 'row'
},
```

Comment: it is not working for  createBottomTabNavigator or createMaterialBottomTabNavigator in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html

Comment: @MayurBaldha yes it works for createBottomTabNavigator  but i cannot center both icon and text in middle

Answer (score 6):

`labelPosition` under `tabBarOptions` seems to have been designed for this.

Reference:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#labelposition

```
  tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: 'blue',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    labelPosition: 'beside-icon',
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `alignself` in the image styling in your icons.

```
Screen4: {
      screen: WalletScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Wallet',
        tabBarIcon: () => (
          <Image
            source={require('./Images/wallet2.png')}
            style={{
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              alignSelf: 'center',
            }}
          />
        ),
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

for "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11" put  tabBarLabelPosition: 'below-icon'in your <Tab.Navigator/> default value is 'beside-icon"

Answer (score 0):

**`tabBarOptions`** is now deprecated in Bottom Tab Navigator's latest version, instead

> **screenOptions**

Here is how I did it :

```
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Your Route Name"
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false, // Change as per your preference
      tabBarLabelPosition: 'beside-icon',
    }}>
```

Rest is normal